# T-SQL Specific Syntax problem (Simple no doubt)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue with a query I'm trying to run on some data, I guess the place to start is to describe the data.

Ok so I have a list of email addresses, each email address has a unique ID and an account ID

Also in my tables I have a set number which auto incrememnts, this will allow me to target duplicate email addresses

What I need to do is something like this.

```
Insert into duplicates
   (EMAIL,ACCOUNTID,ID)

SELECT Email,AccountID,ID
   FROM EmailAddresses

Group by Email,AccountID
   Having Count(email)>1
Order by AccountID, Email
```

So essentially I want to select all duplicate email addresses and insert them (and their relative fields) into a new table broken down by accountID so I can run some further querys on it.

I have been battling with this for way too long and could just use a fresh perspective.

Cheers in advance

Comment: What's the syntax error message? I can't seem to notice any syntax error for that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the ID field in the duplicates table is NOT an identity field and remove the order by clause.

```
Insert into duplicates 
(EMAIL,ACCOUNTID,ID) 
SELECT Email,AccountID, MIN(ID)
FROM EmailAddresses 
Group by Email,AccountID 
Having Count(email)>1
```

If you want all the duplicate records, use the select suggested by queen3

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thankyou and everyone else who posted all of them where helpful and at least taught me something!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM EmailAddresses e1 INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT Email, AccountId
   FROM EmailAddresses
   GROUP BY Email, AccountID
   HAVING Count(Id)>1) Dups 
      ON Dups.Email = e1.Email AND Dups.AccountId = e1.AccountId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Email, AccountID, ID INTO duplicates
FROM EmailAddresses E
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmailAddresses E1 WHERE E1.Email = E.Email) > 1
GROUP BY Email, AccountID, ID;
```